# Adding OpenTK Control to vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, opentk

I am experimenting with OpenTK in VB.net using VS 2012. I have used the Nuget manager to include OpenTK and the OpenTK Control in my project. The Imports statement are in place and don't show errors so I assume they items are correctly loaded.

My next step is to add the OpenTK Control to the form. The examples I found on the web use the Choose Items... option found by right clicking the top of the Toolbox Tree. I then use Browse and select the OpenTK control .dll. I then get an error message saying that there is noting in the .dll that can be added to the toolbox.

I'm obviously missing something very basic!

Chris

Comment: What `control` are you talking about specifically? It is a `library`, not a `UserControl`...

Comment: It is the OpenTK Control that is available via NuGet from within VS 2012.